Como puedo Integrar Twilio con su api.sendgrid.com con Gnx X ev3?
Intento consumir un servicio de Twilio para el envio de correo por medio del uso de su API (api.sendgrid.com) pero no logro determinar porque no me esta funcionando, ya valide con un Cliente SOAP & REST y aquí funciona perfecto, algún ejemplo?, estoy utilizando GeneXus X ev3 upg 15 con C# en Web.

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.
